# Oracle SQL - Create Sequence and add sequence values on new column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sequence

I have the following table called table_1

[image]

I create a new column_3

[image]

then I create a sequence

`CREATE SEQUENCE "sequence_1"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOPARTITION`

and I alter the table_1 so the default for new values on column_3 are the the values of the sequence.

`ALTER TABLE table_1 MODIFY column_3 DEFAULT sequence_1.NEXTVAL`

How can I replace the existing null values on column_3 with the values from this sequence? The final result should be:

[image]

Comment: Does Col3 have a relationship with Col1? Does it matter that your first row is 1,red,1? Can it be 1,red,982?

Comment: @Isolated assume no relationship. It can be 1, red, 982.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but if the goal is to get a random number in col3, then one method is something like this. Here I'm just creating a new table, but you get the idea: `create table t2 as (select id, color, row_number() over (order by DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM) as rn from my_table)`

Comment: @Isolated  column_3 has to be filled by values generated by the sequence e.g. using sequence_1.NEXTVAL on each row for column_3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DB version is `12c+`, then adding an [**identity column**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/22.1/sqlreferencefornosql/identity-column.html) will handle what's needed such as

```
ALTER TABLE table_1 ADD new_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
```

where

- using `GENERATED` and `AS IDENTITY` are mandatory
- There are three following options `[ ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT [ ON NULL ] ]`.
  A value for the identity column is always generated if the `ALWAYS` option is used as in this case. Attempt to insert a value into the identity column will cause an error.
- No need to use `START WITH` and `INCREMENT BY` options for the
  current case. Since those are already **`1`** as default

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ppmkoWNr)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Solution I came up with is the following - happy to accept better answers:

```
ALTER TABLE table_1 ADD column_3 NUMBER(38,0) DEFAULT sequence_1.NEXTVAL NOT NULL
```

Comment: `default on null` is better in my opinion. Adding an identity column would be even better, but there are a couple of steps to adding an identity column to an existing table.